# Second derivative of $\ell_p$ norm of a vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vectors, hessian-matrix

The $\ell_p$-norm of a vector $\mathbf{x}$ is defined as the root of the sum of the absolute values of its elements raised to the power of $p$.

I want to calculate the following derivative.
$$\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial \mathbf{x}^2}\Vert \mathbf{A}^{1/p}\mathbf{x} \Vert_p ^p.$$

I think the first derivative is (not sure if it is correct):

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial \mathbf{x}}\Vert \mathbf{A}^{1/p}\mathbf{x} \Vert_p ^p = p \mathbf{A}^{1/p} |\mathbf{A} ^{1/p} \mathbf{x} |^{p−1},$$

where $| \cdot |$ is the absolute value. Struggling to compute the second derivative.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\l{\lambda}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\ll{\ell_p}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\abs#1{\op{abs}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\sign#1{\op{sign}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\hess#1#2#3{\frac{\p^2 #1}{\p #2\,\p #3}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
$For typing convenience, define the variables
$$\eqalign{
\o &= \{{\rm vector}\,&{\rm of\:ones}\} \\
M &= A^{1/p} \\
v &= Mx   &\qiq \c{dv = M\:dx} \\
b &= \abs{v}  &\qiq b\odot b = v\odot v \\
B &= \Diag{b} &\qiq Bv = b\odot v \\
V &= \Diag{v} &\qiq V\o = v\odot\o = v \\
s &= \sign{v} &\qiq v = s\odot b,\; s = v\oslash b \\
\l &= \LR{\ll}^p \\
}$$
and the Frobenius product, which is a concise notation for the trace
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \frob{A}^2  \\
}$$
The following relationships will prove useful
$$\eqalign{
 v\odot b &= b\odot v &\qiq Vb = Bv = BV\o \\
 b\odot b &= v\odot v &\qiq b\odot db = v\odot dv  \\
 B^2 &= V^2 &\qiq \c{B\:db = V\,dv} \\
 VB &= BV &\quad\{ {\rm diagonal\;matrices\;commute} \} \\
}$$
Use the above notation to write the objective function
and calculate its gradient
$$\eqalign{
 \l &= \o:b^{\odot p} \\
d\l &= \o:\LR{p\,b^{\odot p-1}\odot db} \\
 &= p\,b^{\odot p-2}:\LR{b\odot db} \\
 &= p\,b^{\odot p-2}:\LR{v\odot dv} \\
 &= p\LR{b^{\odot p-2}\odot v}:dv \\
 &= p\LR{B^{\,p-2}\,v}:\CLR{M\,dx} \\
 &= p\LR{M^TB^{\,p-2}\,v}:dx \\
\grad{\l}{x} &= pM^TB^{\,p-2}\,v \;=\; g \quad \{ {\rm gradient} \} \\
}$$
This is almost the same as your result, but you missed the transpose on the $M$ matrix.

Now calculate the gradient of $g$ aka the Hessian
$$\eqalign{
dg &= pM^TB^{\,p-2}\,dv + pM^TdB^{\,p-2}\,v \\
 &= pM^TB^{\,p-2}\,dv + p(p-2)M^TB^{\,p-3}\,dB\;v \\
 &= pM^TB^{\,p-2}\,dv + p(p-2)M^TVB^{\,p-4}\CLR{B\;db} \\
 &= pM^TB^{\,p-2}\,dv + p(p-2)M^TVB^{\,p-4}\CLR{V\,dv} \\
 &= pM^TB^{\,p-2}\,dv + p(p-2)M^TB^{\,p-2}\,dv \\
 &= \LR{p^2-p}M^TB^{\,p-2}\,\CLR{M\,dx} \\
\grad{g}{x}
 &= \LR{p^2-p}M^TB^{\,p-2}\,M \;=\; H \quad \{ {\rm Hessian} \} \\
}$$
As a sanity check, note that $H$ is a symmetric matrix.